# Do Triggers/DataTrigger return to previous state if it is no longer true in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

While reading about [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) on MSDN, it says

> Represents a trigger that applies property values or performs actions when the bound data meets a specified condition.

It means

> When a trigger is true it changes the value to the desired value.

But, can this be inferred?

> When it is no longer true it returns the value to the previous value.

---

**How I came to this conclusion**

I did this

```
<Style x:Key="fd" TargetType="SomeControl">
 <Setter Property="Control.Template">
  <Setter.Value>
   <ControlTemplate>
    <Button Content="Foo" x:Name="mybutton">
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=FooProperty}" 
                  Value="Collapsed">
      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" TargetName="mybutton"/>
      <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" TargetName="mybutton"/>
     </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style>
```

When `FooProperty` becomes collapsed it changes mybutton's `IsEnabled` to `False` and `Opacity` to `0.5`

Now when `FooProperty` becomes visible it changes mybutton's `IsEnabled` to `True` and `Opacity` to `1` even though I have not written any trigger for reverting back to previous values.

Is this an inbuilt feature of `DataTrigger` to revert back to  previous value When it is no longer true?

If yes, is there any Microsoft/MSDN doc to prove this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are telling, is correct.

As for actual doc to prove this,
search from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.aspx

"Remarks section"

> WPF defines properties that correspond to end-user actions, such as
>   the IsMouseOver property that is set to true when the user hovers the
>   cursor over a UIElement or the corresponding IsMouseOver property of a
>   ContentElement. Representing end-user actions in property values,
>   along with the Trigger element, allows WPF styles to change property
>   values based on those end-user actions, all from within markup.
>
> The properties changed by triggers are automatically reset to their
>   previous value when the triggered condition is no longer satisfied.
>   Triggers are optimized for transient states which are expected to
>   change and return to original state, such as IsPressed on Button and
>   IsSelected on ListBoxItem. The Property of interest must be a
>   dependency property.
>
> Note that you must specify both the Property and Value properties on a
>   Trigger for the trigger to be meaningful. If one or both of the
>   properties are not set, an exception is thrown.

good luck :)

Comment: How to avoid resetting ?