# How to set "default" style of WPF control via DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TextBock where I change the style based on a DataTrigger that is triggered via a bound boolean property.
What I want is to change the ForeGround color of my text if the value of the bound property is true.
If it is false I want to use my "default" style (BodyValueStyle1) again.
How I do it so far is:

```
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BodyValueStyle1}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTrueOrFalse}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTrueOrFalse}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

It works fine and does what I want, but what I dont like is the following:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTrueOrFalse}" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Is there a way to "reset" the style to my default style(BodyValueStyle1) instead of setting all properties that I have changed before at the false condition?
Because my default ForeGround color is black in anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `Setter` in `BodyValueStyle1`:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
```

Then you can remove the second `DataTrigger`. The triggers' behavior is already what you would like.

**Sources**

[Another Stack Overflow question with explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489931/do-triggers-datatrigger-return-to-previous-state-if-it-is-no-longer-true-in-wpf)

> The properties changed by triggers are automatically reset to their previous value when the triggered condition is no longer satisfied. Triggers are optimized for transient states which are expected to change and return to original state, such as IsPressed on Button and IsSelected on ListBoxItem. The Property of interest must be a dependency property.