# WPF control not returning in previous state after triggering

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

**XAML**

```
<utility:InvalidNotification x:Name="InvalidNotificationControl"/>
<Button Content="Clean AppV Cache" Click="Button_Click">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=InvalidNotificationControl, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

**NOTE**

`InvalidNotification` is a custom UserControl

Now, the `DataTrigger` works fine initially and disable the button since the Usercontrol is visible.

The problem is when I collapse the Usercontrol based on another condition the button stays disable. I found this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12490075/7692463) which states that *The properties changed by triggers are automatically reset to their previous value when the triggered condition is no longer satisfied.* which is not my case. Why is that ?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @mm8 which led me to the solution. So if ever you're trying to bind a control on a UserControl's **content** (inner `TextBlock` in my case), just add a second trigger at the bottom of your Usercontrol like so,

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="UserControl">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Notification, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

where `notification` would be the name of my `TextBlock`

Comment: You need to show us how you set the Visibility property of the UserControl. This should work. You don't set the IsEnabled property of the Button somewhere else, are you?

Comment: I can provide the code, but it is really straight-foward. I change visibility on a `TextBlock` based on a property value through databinding. Everything works fine concerning the Usercontrol, its visibility is correctly toggling depending on the desired value. Only the button is not.

Comment: @mm8 That would be silly, but I'll check.

Comment: How does setting the Visibility property of a TextBlock change the Visibility of the control that you bind to?

Comment: @mm8 Damn... Just understood my mistake. The button is binded on the usercontrol but I'm actually toggling the visiblity of the Usercontrol **CONTENT** which makes no sense.

Comment: @mm8 Would it be possible to me to bind my button on a Textblock that `InvalidNotification` contains ?

Comment: Not unless you expose the TextBlock from the UserControl using a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works provided that you toggle/set the `Visibility` property of the `InvalidNotification` control itself, since it is this property that you bind to.

If you set the `Visibility` property of some element within the `InvalidNotification` control, you need to bind to this specific element.

You can't do this using an `ElementName` binding though because the `Button` and any element defined in the `InvalidNotification` control don't belong to the same namescope.

Comment: Edited my question with a potential solution. Thanks again.